Creating Spotify-database how to optimize for loops
I'm trying to create a dataset using Spotify API but its very slow.
playlists = {
    "ids": [],
    "messages": []
}

for category_id in categories_df['ids']:
    playlists_data = get_category_playlists(category_id, limit=50, offset=0)
    items = playlists_data['playlists']['items']
    message = playlists_data['message']
    
    # Usamos np.concatenate para adicionar os IDs como um array numpy
    ids = np.array([item['id'] for item in items])
    playlists["ids"] = np.concatenate((playlists["ids"], ids))
    playlists["messages"].extend([message] * len(items)) 

The problem is that categories_df['ids'] has more than 50 items and I'm making 50 for each category and a playlist has more or less 70 songs.
Getting the playlist alone is taking more than 30 seconds.
Is there a way to improve for loops?

You can't for this things but I have some suggestion. Try to index them with category and save in address that next to each other. Like a list, it will be O(1) instead of loop. But the point is how to indexing those songs.

You could try this with asyncio and aiohttp

Does get_category_playlists emit an SQL query like SELECT * FROM playlists WHERE category_id = <something>.  If so, what database backend are you using?
